# Can write sharding prevent all hot partition key situations?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose you had to query by date range on a large block of items every time an application loaded (splash screen).

**Solution 1:**

Create a single partition key `dateManifest` and store all of the dates (`2019-01-25`) as the sort key. This would allow a single query to get all of the items that the UI needs. The problem is obviously that this partition key would be hit on every application launch.

**Solution 2:**

Use write sharding to split the partition key up, such as by month (`dateManifestJan`, `dateManifestFeb`, `dateManifestMar`, ...). The would require multiple queries to populate the UI but it would spread the queries across multiple partitions.

**My question:**

If the default query (to populate the UI on application launch) is to retrieve the entire year, then is there really a benefit to splitting the partition keys up? Because instead of hitting a single partition key on each query (`dateManifest`), you're just hitting the same 12 on each query. And you've created a situation where each partition now has a lower RCU limit because there may be more partitions.

Also, if the query is just for a single month, in January, you're going to overload the `dateManifestJan` partition key and in February overload the `dateManifestFeb` key, and so on. Is that really any better?

Answer (score 0):

Need more info...amount of data, read/writes

Are you even going to have more than one partition?  Regardless of how many partition keys you use, Dynamo will only create multiple partitions if your data is > 10GB or you provision more than 3000 RCU and/or 1000 WCU's.

So if your data is 100GB, you'd have 10 partitions with up to 30,000 RCU and 10,000 WCU available.

If repeated read queries are your concern, consider [DynamoDb Accelerator (DAX).](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.html)

One of the use-cases for DAX is

> Applications that are read-intensive, but are also cost-sensitive. With DynamoDB, you provision the number of reads per second that your application requires. If read activity increases, you can increase your tables' provisioned read throughput (at an additional cost). Alternatively, you can offload the activity from your application to a DAX cluster, and reduce the amount of read capacity units you'd need to purchase otherwise.

Comment: Even if the database is a single partition, aren't hot keys still an issue?

Comment: @hgale no, with a single partition all I/O goes to the one partition anyway.  "hot sharding" is when 1 or more partitions get more I/O than the rest.